# Woocommerce product visibility issue

Tags: php, sql

I'm having an issue with woocommerce I'm not sure how to fix.

I imported a CSV of 800+ products into a test site, when I go into Products > All Products, the number next to all reads (890) but Published (393).

I've tried looking around various articles and can't seem to find how I view these unpublished products and can't see them anywhere in the site.

I've pasted a screenshot of what it's showing, any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you provide any IDs for the products while importing the products? We should not provide the IDs for the products.

WordPress assigns Post IDs to everything that is a Post. So, Posts, Pages, Products, Images, Attachments, etc all get their own ID. It starts at 1, and then goes up. If you see a gap it might mean that you uploaded images in between, or made new blog posts. OR imported 100 products, deleted 100 products, etc.

Basically, it’s perfectly normal to have IDs that are random. IDs are not used in anything except for the database to find what that is. You do not want to assign IDs on import either. Because you don’t know what IDs are already taken and so you might have a problem that way. Best to leave IDs blank when making new products.

Comment: Hi Rajeev Thank you for the info. The IDs were all free when imported. I believe it's some form of visibility issue in relation to unpublished products but not sure how to fix it

Comment: So are you sure you didn't specify any IDs while importing?
Can you check in Pages and Posts whether there is anything displayed there?
Did you use default Woocmmerce importer or any other third party tool?

Comment: Also, you check this URL and see whether you are able to see the Unpublished products? (Replace the DOMAINAME.COM with your WEBSITE URL)
www.domainname.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_status=draft&post_type=product